# Handling long probe paths in systemtap userspace scripts (variables)?

Tags: linux, systemtap

I am trying to instrument a user-space program using `systemtap`, Linux 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP; `stap --version` says: "Systemtap translator/driver (version 2.3/0.158, Debian version 2.3-1ubuntu1.4 (trusty))"

So I first tried getting a list of all callable functions, with:

`stap -L 'process("/home/username/pathone/subpathtwo/subpaththree/subpathfour/subpathFive/subpathsix/subpathSeven/subpatheight/myprogramab").function("*").call' 2>&1 | tee /tmp/stap`

This worked - however, note that the absolute path to my program is massive. So from the `/tmp/stap` file, I read some probes of interest, however, they are even longer, such as:

`process("/home/username/pathone/subpathtwo/subpaththree/subpathfour/subpathFive/subpathsix/subpathSeven/subpatheight/myprogramab").function("DoSomething@/home/username/pathone/subpathtwo/subpaththree/subpathfour/subpathFive/src/BasicTestCodeFileInterface.cpp:201").call`

... and as this is very difficult to read/unreadable for me, I wanted to do something to split this line into more readable pieces. The first thing I thought of was using variables, so I tried this `test.stp` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stap

global exepath = "/home/username/pathone/subpathtwo/subpaththree/subpathfour/subpathFive/subpathsix/subpathSeven/subpatheight/myprogramab"
global srcpath = "/home/username/pathone/subpathtwo/subpaththree/subpathfour/subpathFive/src"

probe begin {
  printf("%s\n", exepath)
  exit() # must have; else probe end runs only upon Ctrl-C
}

probe end {
  newstr = "DoSomething@" . srcpath  # concatenate strings
  printf("%s\n", newstr)
}
```

This works, I can run `sudo stap /path/to/test.stp`, and I get the two strings printed.

However, when I try to use these strings in probes, they fail:

- Writing a probe like this:

`probe process(exepath).function("DoSomething@".srcpath."/BasicTestCodeFileInterface.cpp:201").call { ...`

... fails with: `parse error: expected literal string or number; saw: identifier 'exepath' ...`.

- Trying to put the "process" part in a variable:

`global tproc = process("/home/username/pathone/subpathtwo/subpaththree/subpathfour/subpathFive/subpathsix/subpathSeven/subpatheight/myprogramab")`

... fails with `parse error: expected literal string or number; saw: identifier 'process' ...`.

So, what options do I have, to somehow shorten the probe lines in a script?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use *macros*:

```
@define part1 %(  "/path/part/1" %)
@define part2 %(  "/part/2" %)
probe process(@part1 @part2).function("...") { }
```

Note no explicit concatenation operator between the (macros that expand to) string literals.  The parser will auto-concatenate them, just as in C.